# Usage of DecimalFormat for the following case

Tags: java

I have the following decimal format previously :

```
private static final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

So,

it can change :

```
0.1   -> "0.10"
0.01  -> "0.01"
0.001 -> "0.00"
```

What I wish is

```
0.1   -> "0.10"
0.01  -> "0.01"
0.001 -> "0.001"
```

Is it possible I can achieve so using DecimalFormat?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

DecimalFormat class is not "Thread Safe". So you are better off having static String variable for this format while you should define the DecimalFormat object within your method required method.

Static variable:

```
private static final String decimalFormatStr = "0.00#";
```

.

Local variable in method:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(decimalFormatStr);
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Many people forget that while using DecimalFormat.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Thread-safety. I quickly review all my code and fix them :)

Comment: If you heavily use this format objects for processing and want to reduce overhead of creating and garbage collecting objects of DecimalFormat you can use them through an object pool. Note it increases complexity but increases performance.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, use this:

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00######");
```

The `#` means a digit should be displayed there except for trailing zeros. The `0` means a digit is always displayed, even if it is a trailing zero. The number of decimal places in the formatted string will not exceed the total number of `0`s and `#`s after the dot, so in this example the digits after the 8th decimal place will be truncated.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

System.out.println(f.format(0.1));
System.out.println(f.format(0.01));
System.out.println(f.format(0.001));
```